# Combining two SQL queries in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've been trying for a couple of hours or so this morning to combine two access (Access 365) queries into one statement so I can run a report off of it. I've read around the forums and have tried various combinations but cannot get them to work. I'm not an SQL guru and was wondering if someone can help and point out where I'm going wrong.

I have a table (data) it has 2 relevant columns
Audit username, Attendance Ref Name,
each time an order is created it gets logged,
if it was electronic the user name is "DRIP" if manually entered it gets the logged in user name.

What I would like is one row for each requester with Column one being the requester name (Attendance Ref Name), Column 2 being number of times the requester appears (Total Number of requests), Column 3 total number of times the requester has made it electronically (Total Number of Electronic requests)
so I can produce a 4th column so show me percentages of electronic requests by the requester

What I have working is two queries

WORKING STATMENTS (written in Notepad - I'm omitting the -- line in access):

```
    --Total number of unique requests per requester
    SELECT DISTINCT Data.[Attendance Ref Name], Count(Data.[Attendance Ref Name]) AS [Total Number of requests]
    FROM Data
    GROUP BY Data.[Attendance Ref Name]
```

and

```
    --Total Number of unique requester received electronically per Requester.
    SELECT DISTINCT Data.[Attendance Ref Name], Count(Data.[Attendance Ref Name]) AS [Total Number of Electronic requests]FROM Data WHERE (((Data.[Audit Username])="DRIP"))
    GROUP BY Data.[Attendance Ref Name];
```

WHAT I have tried:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT Data.[Attendance Ref Doctor Name], Count(Data.[Attendance Ref Doctor Name]) AS [Total Number of requests]FROM Data
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT Data.[Attendance Ref Doctor Name], Count(Data.[Attendance Ref Doctor Name]) AS [Total Number of Electronic requests]FROM Data WHERE (((Data.[Audit Username])="DRIP"))
    GROUP BY Data.[Attendance Ref Doctor Name];
```

and

```
    SELECT
    (SELECT DISTINCT Data.[Attendance Ref Doctor Name], Count(Data.[Attendance Ref Doctor Name])FROM Data) AS [Total Number of requests],
    (SELECT DISTINCT Data.[Attendance Ref Doctor Name], Count(Data.[Attendance Ref Doctor Name])FROM Data WHERE Data.[Audit Username]="DRIP")AS [Total Number of Electronic requests]
```

I have even been through https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp tutorials

but I cannot get them working anyone able to help please and put me out of my misery?
thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a join to link the result from your first and second query together.

Assuming all ref names are in both tables, you can use the following:

```
SELECT q1.[Attendance Ref Name], q1.[Total Number of requests], q2.[Total Number of Electronic requests]
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT Data.[Attendance Ref Name], Count(Data.[Attendance Ref Name]) AS [Total Number of requests]
    FROM Data
    GROUP BY Data.[Attendance Ref Name]
) AS q1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT Data.[Attendance Ref Name], Count(Data.[Attendance Ref Name]) AS [Total Number of Electronic requests]FROM Data WHERE (((Data.[Audit Username])="DRIP"))
    GROUP BY Data.[Attendance Ref Name]
) AS q2
ON q1.[Attendance Ref Name] = q2.[Attendance Ref Name]
```

Comment: HI Erik, Is there a way to Show all values for the first part of the query, ie if a requester hasn't made any electronic requests it displays this as 0? Or is this another join?

Comment: If you have a table that shows all the ref names, you can use that as the first table and select the name from it, and then join both tables to it using a `LEFT JOIN`. Then all  missing entries will have `Null`, and not 0, but you can replace `Null` with zero using `Nz(MyField, 0)`